# collideWith Call Back Method

Tags: andengine

In my class, I extend Sprite class. I override one of the method collideWith(). But my problem was that when current sprite collide with other sprite it does not call the call back method collideWith(). Here is my implementation.

```
@Override
public boolean collidesWith(IShape pOtherShape) {
    System.out.println("collide with called");
    return true;
}
```

Any member please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a callback, you have to call the method yourself to find out whether the Sprites collide. By overriding it you broke its functionality. What you want to do (I think) is override the onUpdate method of the Sprite and put there an if statement calling the `collidesWith(otherSprite)` method.

Comment: So what it the advantage to override this method in out user define class.

Comment: There is no reason to override the method collidesWith unless you want to handle the collision checking all by yourself. Overriding onUpdate is just the way of achieving what you want, it will run user-defined code on every step and you're free to do whatever you want with it. Just make the body of onUpdate slim, because this code will run very often and could slow down you application.

Comment: If you override a method, you redefine his behavior. By overriding, you redefine (i suppose) the collision detection process. In java, you can use the "super" operator and do something like super.collideWidth(...)

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify a bit.

First read about about [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

If you have to call it yourself, it's probably not a callback.

In java, you can override a method (maybe you should read about OO concepts) like you did:

```
@Override
public void foo() {
}
```

The method *foo* is override in a custom class that probably extends another class (or implements an interface but in this case you **have to** override all the methods of the interface since they are **abstract**. Read more about interfaces [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).) that contains a *foo* method itself.

```
class ParentClass {

    public void foo() {
        //do something
    }
```

Since overriding a method mean "redefining" his behavior, if you call the *foo* method from your custom class extending *ParentClass* it will (in this case) not do anything. If you want to reach a method from a parent class, use *super*.

```
@Override
public void foo() {
    super.foo(); //will call the foo method of the parent class
    //add custom code here
}
```

Also you should read this great tutorial covering inherence in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html